# EventHandler fires thread only once instead of multiple times due to unhandled boundary case

Tags: c#, multithreading, events

I have an event that listens for tick updates and will get hit 100 times.

Every 10 hits, I add the content for sampling in another method. However this thread/method only gets called once, instead of 9 more times.

I believe it could be caused by `tickList.RemoveRange(0,10)` not being reset to count 0 before another 10 events swarm in...resulting in my If case `(tickList.Count == 10)` never being true again.

Is there some issue here with how I'm calling the thread, or any way to account for this boundary case. So that dropping tick data on the eventHandler is kept to a minimum?

```
    private  static void OnTickUpdated(object source, TickEventArgs args)
    {
       Console.WriteLine(args.Close);
       tickList.Add(args.Close);

        if (tickList.Count == 10)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("We hit sample size");


            Thread runThread = new Thread(() =>
            {
                foreach (var data in tickList)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Sample set, do some work: "  + data);
                }

            });

            runThread.Start();
            if (runThread.ThreadState == ThreadState.Stopped)
            {
                tickList.RemoveRange(0, 10);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, is your TickList is threadsafe? If it isn't you'll end up with concurrent updates which could cause you problems.

I'd strongly suggest using a more appropriate mechanism such as a queue. This then follows the producer/consumer pattern.

Then you could use `if (ticklist.count >= 10)` instead and then pop the first 10 items off as the queue is still being produced. When you pop you're reducing the queue size as expected, but more can still come in without ruining your program flow.

You'd need to ensure that multiple calls aren't made to the queue drain at once, probably by locking the method.

Furthermore, embed the "10" as a constant or configuration somewhere, so if you need to up the size of your batches, it's very simple to do so and not prone to human error.

After the final iteration, ensure you call the queue draining routine to ensure it's empty.